# Setting up BugTracker.NET complete noob

Tags: connection-string, bugtracker.net

This is my first ASP.NET project and I'm stuck right away.

I'm setting up a bugtracker on a remote webhotel but I can't get the connectionstrings to work.
If we say that my host is called hosting.org and my website would be www.trallala.com

what do I have to change in this script?

```
<configSections>
</configSections>

<system.web>

    <!--
    BugTracker.NET is not compatible with Session serialization.

    Timeout session after 120 minutes
    -->

    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120"/>

    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages validateRequest="true" />
    <!-- A few people over the years have needed to override the default IIS settings...
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="51200"/>
    -->

    <!-- for my testing <globalization culture="de-DE" uiCulture="en-US" /> -->

</system.web>
<appSettings>
    <!-- 

        ********* QUICK START *************

        If you want to get started quickly, then just change the following
        and then try to log in:

            ConnectionString
            AbsouteUrlPrefix

        After you can log in and create a bug, then you probably want to
        set up the email integration.  Set up the following:

            ErrorEmailTo
            ErrorEmailFrom

            NotificationEmailEnabled
            NotificationEmailFrom

            And your SMTP settings below.

    -->
    <!--
        Change this to point to your database
    -->

    <add key="ConnectionString" value="server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;database=btnet;user id=sa;password=x;Trusted_Connection=no"/>
    <!--
        Used when creating absolute href's.  For example, in notification emails.
        Don't forget trailing slash!.
    -->
    <add key="AbsoluteUrlPrefix" value="http://127.0.0.1/btnet2/"/>
    <!--
        You can turn the logging and emailing of errors on and off.
        Log file name is "btnet_log_yyyy_mm_dd.txt"

        For the LogFileFolder setting, if you specify the folder starting with a 
        drive letter or the \\ that indicates a UNC path, it's treated as a full path.  
        For example: c:\\something or \\somemachine\something

        Otherwise it's treated as a path relative to where you virtual directory is
        located.

        LogEnabled turns on and off logging as a whole.
        LogSqlEnabled turns on and off just the logging of SQL statements, but
        that's about 98% of what gets logged, so if you want to reduce the
        volume, turn that off.

    -->
    <add key="LogEnabled" value="1"/>
    <add key="LogSqlEnabled" value="1"/>
    <add key="LogFileFolder" value="App_Data\logs"/>
    <!-- If BugTracker.NET itself experiences an error, it can send an email notification -->
    <add key="ErrorEmailEnabled" value="1"/>
    <add key="ErrorEmailTo" value="YOUR EMAIL HERE"/>
    <add key="ErrorEmailFrom" value="FROM EMAIL HERE"/>


    <!--
        You can "subscribe" to email notifications on a per-bug basis.
        You will receive an email whenever the bug is updated.
    -->
    <add key="NotificationEmailEnabled" value="1"/>
    <add key="NotificationEmailFrom" value="FROM EMAIL HERE"/>

    <!--
        This controls the format of the subject of the email notifications.
        The available variables are:
        $THING$ - from the "SingularBugLabel" setting
        $BUGID$
        $ACTION$ - added or changed
        $SHORTDESC$
        $PROJECT$
        $CATEGORY$
        $ORGANIZATION$
        $PRIORITY$
        $STATUS$
        $TRACKINGID$ - from the "TrackingIdString" setting
    -->
    <add key="NotificationSubjectFormat" value="$THING$:$BUGID$ was $ACTION$ - $SHORTDESC$ $TRACKINGID$"/>

    <!--
        If you aren't using the local SMTP server that comes with IIS,
        set the name, user, and password for your SMTP server here.
    -->

    <!-- Sample SMTP Settings -->

    <!--
        These settings work with my SBC account
    -->
    <!--
    <add key="SmtpServer" value="smtp.att.yahoo.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerAuthenticateUser" value="ctrager@sbcglobal.net"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerPort" value="465"/>
    <add key="SmtpUseSSL" value="1"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerAuthenticatePassword" value="MY PASSWORD"/>
    -->
    <!--
        These settings work with my GMail account
    -->
    <!--
    <add key="SmtpServer" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerAuthenticateUser" value="ctrager@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerPort" value="465"/>
    <add key="SmtpUseSSL" value="1"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerAuthenticatePassword" value="MY PASSWORD"/>
    -->


    <!--
        These settings work with my GoDaddy account
    -->

    <!--        
    <add key="SmtpServer" value="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerAuthenticateUser" value="ctrager@ifdefined.com"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerAuthenticatePassword" value="MY PASSWORD"/>
    <add key="SmtpServerPort" value="25"/>      
    -->

    <!--
        Specify the pickup directory if you have the problem described here:
        http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;816789#8
    -->

    <!--
    <add key="SmtpServerPickupDirectory" value=""/>
    <add key="SmtpSendUsing" value="1"/>
    -->


    <!--
        Ignore this setting unless you are esperiencing the symptoms
        related to this: http://cr.yp.to/docs/smtplf.html
    -->
    <!--
    <add key="SmtpForceReplaceOfBareLineFeeds" value="1"/>
    -->
    <!--
        By default, emails are UTF8 encoded.  If that doesn't work for you,
        uncomment the following.
    -->
    <!--
    <add key="BodyEncodingUTF8" value="0"/>
    -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Persist Security Info=true;User ID=bugtracker;Password=bugs;Initial Catalog=BugTracker;Data Source=[IP ADDRESS]" />
```

This is what you'd need to add/edit in the web.config.  once it's setup, BugTracker will run the scripts to create the proper database elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that "ConnectionString" points to the right Database and has the right username and password for DB-access.

You might want to make sure that your Database is actually up and running and that the username and password are correct by simply trying to log in as that user in your DB.

If that doesn't work, than the problem doesn't lie with your asp.net configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The [BugTracker.NET documentation](http://ifdefined.com/README.html#connection) includes this section on connection strings:

The hardest part ...for most people is getting the ConnectionString to work.

For help, see these links, the "SqlConnection (.NET)" sections
http://www.connectionstrings.com/?carrier=sqlserver2005
http://www.sqlstrings.com/SQL-Server-connection-strings.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-3513_11-6084879.html

Another thing you might try to get the connection string right is the following:

1. Create a new blank file and name it test.udl.
2. Double click on it, and a "Data Link Properties" dialog should appear.
3. On "Providers" tab, select "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" or "SQL Native Client"
4. On "Connections" tab, try various settings and use the "Test Connection" button to test them. Click "Ok" when it works.
5. Open the test.udl file in Notepad and copy the line that starts with "Provider=" into your Web.config "ConnectionString" value, BUT delete the little part that says "Provider=SQLNCLI.1;"